# can't access the element in the ArrayList in java

Tags: java, class, arraylist, indexing, element

```
for(int i = 0; i < req.dependsRequirement.size(); i++) {
    if(req.dependsRequirement.get(i).hasDesplayed == false)
```

I have created an `ArrayList`.

I want to access the element in index `i`, but when I use `get(i)` the compiler gives me a syntax error.

To understand the program
I have created a class `Requirement` that has 3 attributes (name, hasDisplayed, and ArrayList of `Requirement`)

Comment: Prepare and post your [mcve].

Comment: Please include information/text from the syntax error you're getting. Also, what's the datatype of "dependsRequirement"? Is that the `ArrayList`?

Comment: most obvious explanation: Type of `req.dependsRequirement` is `Collection` and not `List`, which has `size()` but not `get(int)`.

Comment: `hasDesplayed` is not the same as `hasDisplayed`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. Only with it someone can detect the exact reason of your issue.

But I can suppose that the problem connected with a type of object that you are trying to parse and take hasDesplayed parameter from it.

So here I just assume what code structure you have based on your question details and provide a valid code for it. You should use a Collection type.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Requirement requirement1 = new Requirement();
        requirement1.setName("Req1");
        requirement1.setHasDisplayed(true);
        Requirement requirement2 = new Requirement();
        requirement2.setName("Req2");
        requirement2.setHasDisplayed(false);
        Requirement requirement3 = new Requirement();
        requirement3.setName("Req3");
        requirement3.setHasDisplayed(true);

        ArrayList<Requirement> requirementList = new ArrayList<>(); // You need to parse this object

        requirementList.add(requirement1);
        requirementList.add(requirement2);
        requirementList.add(requirement3);

        Requirement requirementSummary = new Requirement(); // But I suppose you parse some kind of this object
        requirementSummary.setRequirement(requirementList);

        for (int i = 0; i < requirementList.size(); i++) {
            if (requirementList.get(i).hasDisplayed == false) {
                System.out.println(requirementList.get(i).getName());
            }

        }
    }

    static class Requirement {
        String name;
        Boolean hasDisplayed;
        ArrayList<Requirement> requirement;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Boolean getHasDisplayed() {
            return hasDisplayed;
        }

        public void setHasDisplayed(Boolean hasDisplayed) {
            this.hasDisplayed = hasDisplayed;
        }

        public ArrayList getRequirement() {
            return requirement;
        }

        public void setRequirement(ArrayList requirement) {
            this.requirement = requirement;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "RequirementDetails{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", hasDisplayed=" + hasDisplayed +
                    ", requirement=" + requirement +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public class Requirement {
 String name;
 **Collection**<Requirement> dependsRequirement = new ArrayList<Requirement>();
 boolean hasDesplayed = false;